# Split integer into two concatenated hex strings- Python

Tags: python, hex, bit-manipulation

I need to transmit a value that is larger than 65535 via two different hex strings so that when the strings are received, they can be concatenated to form the integer again. For example if the value was 70000 then the two strings would be 0x0001 and 0x1170.

I thought it would be as simple as converting the integer to hex then shifting it right by 4 to get the top string and removing all but the last 4 characters for the bottom.

I think I might be struggling with some syntax (fairly new to Python) and probably some of the logic too. Can anyone think of an easy way to do this?

Thanks

Comment: Wouldn't it be easier to just send the data as a String?

Comment: I am using the Modbus protocol which requires me to send them as two hexadecimal numbers (one for each register)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `divmod` builtin function:

```
>>> [hex(x) for x in divmod(70000, 65536)]
['0x1', '0x1170']
```

Comment: for `65540` it returns `['0x1', '0x4']` and `hex(65540)` equals `0x10004`, means you lost three `0`'s.

Comment: Well, you'll need something like ['%#06x' % x for x in divmod(num, 65536)] if you need the full four digits in each string. But you don't; the simple way to reverse this is (int(big) << 16) | int(small)

Answer (score 1):

You mean like this?

```
In [1]: big = 12345678
In [2]: first, second = hex(big)[2:][:-4], hex(big)[2:][-4:]
In [3]: first, second
Out[3]: ('bc', '614e')

In [4]: int(first+second, 16)
Out[4]: 12345678
```

Comment: This won't work for numbers under 65536. For example, with 1234, you'll get '' and 'x4d2'.

Comment: @abarnert The OP explicitly stated it was > 65536, but OK, the edit should fix it.

Comment: Well, it sort of works now, if you consider '' to be a reasonable hex representation of 0. But from the OP's post, I don't think he does: "the two strings would be 0x0001 and 0x1170".

Comment: @abarnert Fair enough. Well, I don't think I can improve the answer without rewriting it from scratch, and besides a proper answer has been given.

Comment: I suppose your answer is ideal for pointing out the flaw in the original problem description, because it implements exactly what was in the spec.

Answer (score 1):

Your algorithm can be implemented easily, as in Lev Levitsky's answer:

```
hex(big)[2:-4], hex(big)[-4:]
```

However, it will fail for numbers under 65536.

You could fix that, but you're probably better off splitting the number, then converting the two halves into hex, instead of splitting the hex string.

ecatmur's answer is probably the simplest way to do this:

```
[hex(x) for x in divmod(70000, 65536)]
```

Or you could translate your "shift right/truncate" algorithm on the numbers like this:

```
hex(x >> 16), hex(x & 0xFFFF)
```

If you need these to be strings like '0x0006' rather than '0x6', instead of calling hex on the parts, you can do this:

```
['%#06x' % (x,) for x in divmod(x, 65536)]
```

Or, using the more modern string formatting style:

```
['0x{:04x}'.format(x) for x in divmod(x, 65536)]
```

But on the other side, you again probably want to undo this by converting to ints first and then shifting and masking the numbers, instead of concatenating the strings. The inverse of ecatmur's answer is:

```
int(bighalf) * 65536 + int(smallhalf)
```

The (equivalent) inverse of the shift/mask implementation is:

```
(int(bighalf) << 16) | int(smallhalf)
```

And in that case, you don't need the extra 0s on the left.

It's also worth pointing out that none of these algorithms will work if the number can be negative, or greater than 4294967295, but only because the problem is impossible in those cases.

Comment: Yes, it returns 0x1 for the big half and 0x4 for the small half. If you put those back together with the inverse operation int(0x1) * 65536 + int(0x4), you get 65540 back.

Answer (score 0):

for numbers greater than `65536` or for numbers whose with length `>=5`, you can use `slicing`:

```
>>> num=70000
>>> var1=hex(num)[:-4]
>>> var2='0x'+hex(num)[-4:]
>>> integ=int(var1+var2[2:],16)
>>> print(integ)
    70000
```

Comment: This only works for 5-digit hex numbers. Try it with num=7000000 instead; you'll get 0x6 and 0xacfc0, which is wrong.

Comment: @abarnert just to stick to OP's method I changed the slicing.

Comment: Your new method now handles numbers over 5 digits long, but still doen't work on numbers under 5 digits. Try it with 1, and you'll get '', '0x0x1'. Of course that's a problem with the OP's original description, that you've just faithfully implemented. But the answer probably won't help him unless you explain that problem, and show how to work around it.

Comment: @abarnert I think the OP is only concerned with numbers larger than `65536`.

Comment: I doubt it. Look at his comment: he needs to send two hexadecimal numbers, one for each register. If his value happens to be, say, 20000, I doubt he wants to send 20000 to the low register and leave around whatever value happens to be sitting in the high register; he probably wants to send 20000 and 0.

Answer (score 0):

Being wary of big/little endians, what you could do to keep it simple is:

```
val = 70000
to_send = '{:08X}'.format(val) # '00011170'
decoded = int('00011170', 16) # 70000
```

**EDIT: to be very clear then...**

```
hex1, hex2 = to_send[:4], to_send[4:] # send these two and on receipt
my_number = int(hex1 + hex2, 16)
```

Comment: This doesn't answer the OP's main question, which is how to split the one big number (or hex string) into two halves.

Comment: @abarnert I'm trusting that the OP can slice the result string into 4 chars each, and I believe his issue was how to generate them